# opening presentOptionsMenuFromRect:inView:animated: at a specific orientation

Tags: objective-c, ios

I am trying to use `presentOptionsMenuFromRect:inView:animated:` to open the Options Menu at a specific orientation. I know how to select the location the anchor points to, but is there a way I can control the orientation of the menu itself - to decide whether I want it to open above/below/left/right from the anchor position?
I couldn't find any reference to it, and I tried to supply the Rect parameter with size, just to see what happens - it didn't affect the menu at all.
Is there a way to control the options menu?